# I need display the data by each user table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how can display for each user the data this is my code

Model

```php
# User Model
public function client()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\Client');
}
```

```php
# Client data Model
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Http\Models\User');
}
```

```php
# Controller
public function porteil()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $client = User::find($user_id);

    return view ('client.show', $this->data)->with('clients', $client)
    ->with('progresing', Progress::all());   
}
```

View

```xml
@foreach($clients as $client)
    <tr class="text-center">
        <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
        <td class="nowrap">{{ $client->n_dossier }}</td>                
        <td class="nowrap">{{ $client->user['name'] }}</td>
        <td class="nowrap">{{ $client->progress['name'] }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <span class="badge badge-yellow">Télécharger</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Your relationships seem off, `belongsTo` is supposed to be the inverse of a `hasOne` or a `hasMany`. For instance a user might "have" many clients, where each client "belongs to" a user.

Comment: What are you currently seeing, btw? Do you see any rows at all?

Answer (score 0):

You may [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) your relationships using `with` method:

```php
public function porteil()
{
    $clients = Client::with(['user', 'progress'])->get();

    return view('client.show', $this->data)
        ->with('clients', $clients)
        ->with('progresing', Progress::all());   
}
```

And on your blade:

```php
@foreach($clients as $client)
    <tr class="text-center">
        <th class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"></th>
        <td class="nowrap">{{$client->n_dossier}}</td>              
        <td class="nowrap">{{$client->user->name}}</td>
        <td class="nowrap">{{$client->progress->name}}</td>
        <td class="text-center">
            <span class="badge badge-yellow">Télécharger</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```